# I can't access my custom magento API?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4, phpstorm

I am new to magento. I have created the custom Magento Api to follow the [Marius instructions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/how-to-creating-custom-soap-xml-rpc-v1-v2-api-in-magento).

my code is:

**app/code/local/Course/Mca/etc/api.xml - the api declaration file.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <mca_mca translate="title" module="mca">
                <title>Mca API</title>
                <model>mca/mca_api</model>
                <acl>mca/mca</acl><!-- acl resource alias -->
                <methods><!-- definne the methods -->

                    <create translate="title" module="mca"><!-- add Mca -->
                        <title>Add Mca</title>
                        <acl>mca/mca/create</acl>
                    </create>

                    <info translate="title" module="mca"><!-- project details -->
                        <title>Retrieve project info</title>
                        <acl>mca/mca/info</acl>
                    </info>

                </methods>
                <faults module="mca"><!-- errors that might appear-->
                    <mca_not_exists>
                        <code>101</code>
                        <message>Requested Mca does not exist.</message>
                    </mca_not_exists>
                    <invalid_data>
                        <code>102</code>
                        <message>Provided data is invalid.</message>
                    </invalid_data>
                    <save_error>
                        <code>103</code>
                        <message>Error while saving Mca. Details in error message.</message>
                    </save_error>
                    <remove_error>
                        <code>104</code>
                        <message>Error while removing Mca. Details in error message.</message>
                    </remove_error>
                </faults>
            </mca_mca>
        </resources>
        <resources_alias>
            <mca>mca_mca</mca>
        </resources_alias>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <mca>mcaMca</mca>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
        <acl><!-- acl definition -->
            <resources>
                <mca translate="title" module="mca">
                    <title>mca</title>
                    <mca translate="title" module="mca">
                        <title>Students</title>
                        <sort_order>110</sort_order>

                        <create translate="title" module="mca">
                            <title>Create</title>
                        </create>

                        <info translate="title" module="mca">
                            <title>Info</title>
                        </info>

                    </mca>
                </mca>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Course/Mca/etc/wsdl.xml** - wsdl part for V2

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />

            <complexType name="mcaMcaCreateEntity"><!-- define type for add project -->
                <all>
                    <element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <element name="telephone" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />

                </all>
            </complexType>

            <complexType name="mcaMcaInfoEntity"><!-- define type for retrieve info -->
                <all>
                    <element name="mca_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <element name="telephone" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />

                    <element name="created_time" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <element name="updated_time" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                </all>
            </complexType>

        </schema>
    </types>
    <!--[+] define messages -->

    <message name="mcaMcaCreateRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="data" type="xsd:string"  />
    </message>
    <message name="mcaMcaCreateResponse">
        <part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>

    <message name="mcaMcaInfoRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="projectId" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="mcaMcaInfoResponse">
        <part name="result" type="typens:mcaMcaInfoEntity" />
    </message>
    <!--[-] define messages -->
    <!--[+] define portTypes -->
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="mcaMcaCreate">
            <documentation>Create the Mca</documentation>
            <input message="typens:mcaMcaCreateRequest" />
            <output message="typens:mcaMcaCreateResponse" />
        </operation>

        <operation name="mcaMcaInfo">
            <documentation>Retrieve MCA info</documentation>
            <input message="typens:mcaMcaInfoRequest" />
            <output message="typens:mcaMcaInfoResponse" />
        </operation>

    </portType>
    <!--[-] define portTypes -->
    <!--[+] define binding -->
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

        <operation name="mcaMcaCreate">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>

        <operation name="mcaMcaInfo">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>

    </binding>
    <!--[-] define portTypes -->
    <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**app/code/local/Course/Mca/etc/wsi.xml** - it's similar to wsdl.xml but it's used for WS-I complience

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
                  targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">

            <xsd:complexType name="mcaMcaCreateEntity">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="telephone" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:element name="mcaMcaCreateRequestParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="data" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="mcaMcaCreateResponseParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:complexType name="mcaMcaInfoEntity">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="mca_id" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="telephone" type="xsd:string" />

                    <xsd:element name="created_time" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="updated_time" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:element name="mcaMcaInfoRequestParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="projectId" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="mcaMcaInfoResponseParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="typens:mcaMcaInfoEntity" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="mcaMcaCreateRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:mcaMcaCreateRequestParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="mcaMcaCreateResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:mcaMcaCreateResponseParam"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">

        <wsdl:operation name="mcaMcaCreate">
            <wsdl:documentation>Add Mca</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="typens:mcaMcaCreateRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="typens:mcaMcaCreateResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:message name="mcaMcaInfoRequest">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:mcaMcaInfoRequestParam" />
        </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:message name="mcaMcaInfoResponse">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:mcaMcaInfoResponseParam" />
        </wsdl:message>

    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

        <wsdl:operation name="mcaMcaCreate">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="mcaMcaInfo">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

app/code/local/Course/Mca/Model/Mca/Api.php - model for handling the Api v1 requests (and some V2 requests)

```
 <?php
class Course_Mca_Model_Mca_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{

    /**
     * init mca students
     * @access protected
     * @param $mcaId
     * @return Course_Mca_Model_Mca
     */
    protected function _initMca($mcaId){
        $mca = Mage::getModel('mca/mca')->load($mcaId);
        if (!$mca->getId()) {
            $this->_fault('mca_not_exists');
        }
        return $mca;
    }

    /**
     * Add Students
     * @access public
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function create($data){
        try {
            if (is_null($data)){
                throw new Exception(Mage::helper('mca')->__("Data cannot be null"));
            }
            $mca = Mage::getModel('mca/mca')->setData((array)$data)->save();
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $mca->getId();
    }

    /**
     * get info
     * @access public
     * @param int $mcaId
     * @return array
     */
    public function info($mcaId){
        $result = array();
        $mca = $this->_initMca($mcaId);
        $result = $mca->getData();
        return $result;
    }

    public function items($filters)
    {
    }

    public function update($stuId, $stuData)
    {
    }

    public function delete($stuId)
    {
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Course/Mca/Model/Mca/Api/V2.php - model for handling the Api v2 requests

```
 <?php
class Course_Mca_Model_Mca_Api_V2 extends Course_Mca_Model_Mca_Api
{

    /**
     * Add Students
     * @access public
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function create($data){
        try {
            if (is_null($data)){
                throw new Exception(Mage::helper('mca')->__("Data cannot be null"));
            }
            $mca = parent::create($data);
            $mca = Mage::helper('api')->wsiArrayPacker($mca);
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $mca->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Project info
     * @access public
     * @param int $mcaId
     * @return object
     */
    public function info($mcaId){
        $result = parent::info($mcaId);
        $result = Mage::helper('api')->wsiArrayPacker($result);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

It is showing the SOAP/XML-RPC list as well WSDL and I created username and api to given permission to access the Mca Api.

[image]

[image]

Finally I invoking the my php file it's returning an error.

my php code is:

```
 <?php 
//$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/ics/index.php/api/soap?wsdl'); //edit the address and put the url to your magento here
//$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/ics/index.php/api/?wsdl');
try
{

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/ics/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login("magento","magento@123"); // put in the info for your user here
echo "Login ID : $sessionId";

echo '<br/>';

//$params = array('param1'=>'Dotnet','param2'=>'Php','param3'=>'9676588589');

//v1
//$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'mca.create',$params);

//v2
$result = $proxy->mcaMcaCreate($sessionId, 'Dotnet','Php','9676588589');

print_r($result); 


$proxy->endSession($sessionId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
    echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
}
```

Error is:
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a short guess, I think your calls should look like this: v1: $result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'mca_mca.create',$params); ////// v2: $result = $proxy->mcaMcaCreate($sessionId, $params); Does that work?

Comment: Hi Anna Volki,I tried but, v1: is returning same(above) error. and v2: is returning time out error.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, Can you look on my thread? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/my-custom-api-returning-inserted-record-id-but-data-is-inserting-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kind of error which shows that Magento doesn't find the method of your API. So you have an issue how you define this method in the api.xml. By the way I saw several potential issues. See below

- You don't need to create again the public function `create` in your class `Course_Mca_Model_Mca_Api_V2` because you extend `Course_Mca_Model_Mca_Api` and this one has the same method.
- Your method `Course_Mca_Model_Mca_Api::create` expects a string as a parameter and a string as a returned value, in your WSDL definition, you define a kind of array (which is anyway badly defined). For your test purpose and to allow you a step by step coding, do:

Replace in wsdl.xml

```
<message name="mcaMcaCreateRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="data" type="typens:mcaMcaCreateEntity" />
</message>
<message name="mcaMcaCreateResponse">
    <part name="result" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
```

With

```
<message name="mcaMcaCreateRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="data" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
<message name="mcaMcaCreateResponse">
    <part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

- You will have to update also the wsi.xml file like you did for the wsdl.xml file
- Into api.xml, you have maybe some issue too, do the following:

Replace

```
    <resources_alias>
        <mca>mca_mca</mca>
    </resources_alias>
    <v2>
        <resources_function_prefix>
            <mca>mcamca</mca>
        </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>
```

with

```
    <resources_alias>
        <mca>mca_mca</mca>
    </resources_alias>
    <v2>
        <resources_function_prefix>
            <mca>mcaMca</mca>
        </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>
```

Then in your test code, use the V2 Soap Version

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/ics/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('magento', 'magento@123');
$result = $proxy->mcaMcaCreate($sessionId, 'my text test');
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi sylvain, I updated my code but it's return Login ID : 83a8da94ee848c4c6f520fc785fc68f8
**Error:
Invalid api path**.

Comment: Marius was right, I edited my answer for the `resources_alias` of the V1 Version however for V2 the fix is correct. it will fix the invalid path error

Comment: Hi SylvainRaye, I have update my code please look into my post. the error is:Call to a member function getId() on a non-object. Can you help me out?

Comment: Hi sylvain, can you see my thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/my-custom-api-returning-inserted-record-id-but-data-is-inserting-null

Comment: @ManojKumar I'll take a look later, I have some work :-)

Comment: Can you look on my thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/my-custom-api-returning-inserted-record-id-but-data-is-inserting-null

Comment: v1 is inserting, but v2: is returning error can you tell me where I went wrong? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9638/v1-is-inserting-data-and-v2-is-returning-soap-error-encoding-object-has-no

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem.
In `api.xml` you have this:

```
<resources>
    <mca translate="title" module="mca">
        <title>Mca API</title>
        ....
```

This should be

```
<resources>
    <mca_mca translate="title" module="mca">
        <title>Mca API</title>
        ....
```

If you look closely at the example I gave [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9502/146), there was this in api.xml

```
<api>
    <resources>
        <portfolio_project translate="title" module="portfolio">
```

So the tag under the `<resources>` should be `<[module]_[entity]>`. In your case the module and the entity have the same name `mca`, so it should be `<mca_mca>`

Comment: hi marius, v1: is displaying my result. but v2: is return Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\WS.php(above php file code) on line 4 error.

Comment: @ManojKumar this may not be code related. The magento api is not fast. You can enable the cache for wsdl from system->cache management to make it a little faster. Also, being on a local machine you may want to increase the max_execution_time

Comment: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'firstname' property error is came.

Comment: Hi Marius, is need to change settings->configurations->services->magento core Api->General settings group->WS-I Compliance = yes?

Comment: Hi Marius, Can you help out my bug? SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'firstname' property error.

Comment: @ManojKumar I think you get this error because you send a string as parameter in your api call and the method expects an object (or array). take a look at what SylvainRayé answered. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Hi Marius, I follow the Sylvain instructions but it's return the  Login ID : 83a8da94ee848c4c6f520fc785fc68f8 **Error: Invalid api path**.

Comment: This should help you debug your problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store. Like I said, most probably you are sending the data wrong. The API works fine.

Comment: @ManojKumar you should care about what you expect as input and output. It means the mapping of data and their format (string, int or complexArray) must be the same between what is defined into the wsdl.xml file and what is generated by your API method. Take a look with other existing API calls to understand how it works (e.g. Catalog API). To debug SOAP client call I did an implementation which works only with Zend Debugger (probably something similar exist for Xdebug). Check the code https://gist.github.com/diglin/7023225

Comment: Hi Marius, I have update my code please look into my post. the error is:Call to a member function getId() on a non-object. Can you help me out?

Comment: Hi Marius, can you fix my thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/my-custom-api-returning-inserted-record-id-but-data-is-inserting-null

Comment: @ManojKumar. I'll try, but I can't right now.

Comment: @Marius, Can you look on my thread? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/my-custom-api-returning-inserted-record-id-but-data-is-inserting-null