# Invalid api path?

Tags: api, magento-1.6, php-5.4, soap, phpstorm

I have created v1 & v2 API successfully and invoking 
the all methods to fallow the **Marius & Sylvain** instructions.

v1 & v2 all methods are successfully running except v1: update method.

v1:
**1)update ->Invalid api path Error?**

can any one tell me where I went wrong?

my code is:

```
<?php 
//$proxy = new SoapClient('http://IPAddress/ics/index.php/api/soap?wsdl'); //edit the address and put the url to your magento here
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/ics/index.php/api/?wsdl');
try
{

$sessionId = $proxy->login("magento","magento@123");


$result = $proxy->call($sessionId,'mca.mcaMcaUpdate',array('1',array('firstname'=>'Manoj','lastname'=>'Kumar','telephone'=>'97012365478')));

print_r($result); 


$proxy->endSession($sessionId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
    echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the url once ... your url is

```
"http://localhost/ics/index.php/api/?wsdl"
```

but it should be

```
 "http://localhost/ics/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl"
```

Comment: I tried this url also but not working.

Comment: have u created your own module for api?? or extended the functionality??

Comment: my own module api. v1 & v2 versions all methods are working except v1:update method.

Comment: magento core is having default module is as named "Api and SoapController is controller name. If you have created your own module then use http://localhost/ics/index.php/<urModuleName>/<controllerName>/<method>

Comment: is compulsory or optional? Am not create any controller for api. in model file creating methods and registering the wsdl.xml,api.xml and wsi.xml. all methods are working except **v1:update method**