# Invalid api path magento buit in api

Tags: magento-1.7, php, soap-api-v2

I have created customized api for magento. Some built in api's call like "catalogCategoryTree" giving error: "Invalid api path" 
below are the files which I have created for custom api

api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <api>

    <resources>

      <masterapi_loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/loginmodel_api</model>
        <title>Demo Custommoduleapi API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/loginmodel</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <customerlogin translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of masterapi</title>
          </customerlogin>

        </methods>
      </masterapi_loginmodel>



       <masterapi_category translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/category_api</model>
        <title>Demo category API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/category</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <getCat translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of filters</title>
          </getCat>

          <getCProductinfo translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of filters</title>
          </getCProductinfo>

        </methods>
      </masterapi_category>



       <masterapi_catproduct translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/catproduct_api</model>
        <title>Demo Catproduct API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/catproduct</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <getCat translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of filters</title>
          </getCat>



        </methods>
      </masterapi_catproduct>



    </resources>




    <resources_alias>

      <loginmodel>masterapi_loginmodel</loginmodel>
      <category>masterapi_category</category>
      <catproduct>masterapi_catproduct</catproduct>

    </resources_alias>



    <v2>
      <resources_function_prefix>

         <loginmodel>masterapiLoginmodel</loginmodel>
         <category>masterapiCategory</category> 
         <catproduct>masterapiCatproduct</catproduct>

      </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>



    <acl>
      <resources>
        <masterapi translate="title" module="masterapi">
          <title>Loginmodel</title>
          <sort_order>5</sort_order>

          <loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
          </loginmodel>

           <category translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
          </category>

           <catproduct translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
           </catproduct>


        </masterapi>

      </resources>
    </acl>
  </api>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycustom_Masterapi>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Mycustom_Masterapi>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <masterapi>

        <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Model</class>

        <rewrite>
           <product>Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Catproduct</product>
         </rewrite>

      </masterapi>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <masterapi>
        <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Helper</class>
      </masterapi>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">

  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />


      <complexType name="filterInfo">
        <sequence>
          <element name="filterName" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="name" type="xsd:string[]"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>

      <complexType name="fieldInfo">
        <sequence>
          <element name="entity_id" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>

      <complexType name="fieldInfoArray">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:fieldInfo[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>


      <!---Declare our types-->
            <complexType name="catalogCategoryID">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="category_id" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
       <!---Declare our input and output parameters-->
            <element name="catalogCategoryGetIDRequestParam">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="catalogCategoryGetIDResponseParam">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
            <!---here we use the type we declared earlier as our output parameter-->
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="typens:catalogCategoryID" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <!---Boohoo-->


    </schema>
  </types>


  <!-- message  -->

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="user" type="xsd:string" />
     <part name="pass" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListResponse">
    <part name="customlogin" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>

  <message name="masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />

  </message>

   <message name="catalogCategoryGetIDResponse">
        <part name="parameters" type="xsd:array" />
    </message>


   <!-- Product info Msg -->

    <message name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="category_cat_id" type="xsd:int" />

  </message>

    <message name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoResponse">
        <part name="parameters" type="xsd:array" />
    </message>
    <!-- END Product info Msg -->


  <!-- portType 2nd -->
  <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">

    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListRequest" />
      <output message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListResponse" />
    </operation>

    <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCat">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest" />
      <output message="typens:catalogCategoryGetIDResponse" />
    </operation>


     <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfo">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoRequest" />
      <output message="typens:masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoResponse" />
    </operation>



     <operation name="masterapiCatproductGetCat">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest" />
      <output message="typens:catalogCategoryGetIDResponse" />
    </operation>

  </portType>




  <!-- binding  1st -->
  <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />


    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>

     <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCat">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>


    <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>


    <operation name="masterapiCatproductGetCat">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>

  </binding>



  <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
      <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

.php

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Mycustom/Masterapi/Model/Loginmodel/Api.php
class Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Loginmodel_Api 
{
  public function customerlogin($user,$pass)
  {

  /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setWebsiteId(1);
        try
        {
            $session->login( $user, $pass);
            $customer = $session->getCustomer();

            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'valid', 'userData' => $customer->getId()));
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'invalid', 'userData' => $e->getMessage()));
        }

   // return $arr_products;
   //return 'true'.$user.'+'.$pass;

  }
}
```

V2.php

```
Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Loginmodel_Api
{
}
```

Comment: check this maybe it helps: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/14778/146

Comment: Hi Marius thanks for the reply. I am able to access my custom api, but I am not able to wok out with built in api like "catalogCategoryTree".As it is giving "invalid api path" Am I doing anything wrong while creating custom api?

Comment: Hi Marius I am getting the error for "catalogCategoryTree" api "SoapFault - faultcode: '3' faultstring: 'Invalid api path.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null".

Comment: check in the code for the text `Invalid api path.` and try to debug from there.

Comment: Sorry Marius I dint get your point. Please tell me in which code I have to check Invalid api path?

Comment: look in the magento core files for the text `Invalid api path.`. That is where the code execution ends up at one point. Then start debugging from there. See the conditions when this exception is thrown and maybe you will realize what your problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26193/discussion-between-gururaj-and-marius).

Comment: HI Marius I am getting error in server when i call "catalogCategoryTree"

 in server "2015-07-24T12:19:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined offset: 1/home/outthinking/public_html/mobileapp3/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php"