# Rest API - how to get custom attributes

Tags: api, soap, rest-api

I use the magento (1.7.0.2) rest API to receive sales orders and product information. This works fine. The problem is that we have added custom attributes to our products. A customer can choose those options when adding a product to his shopping cart. 
But these custom attributes are not shown in the received rest API result. I also tried SOAP V1 and V2 API - no luck.

How can I get those custom attributes?

Comment: can you tell me which methods are you used?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend the API to support your custom attributes:

- [How can I create a Custom SOAP/XML-RPC v1 & V2 Api in magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/how-can-i-create-a-custom-soap-xml-rpc-v1-v2-api-in-magento)

Comment: that's not possible because I am not the owner of the shop. But I found a solution to parse the sales order page from the backend with a custom htmlClient.