# Magento SOAP, getting simple products associated with configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, api, soap

I'm importing products from Magento using with the SOAP API V2. Everything is Ok but I get simple products and configurable products as unrelated objects.

How can I get the association between configurable and simple products?

This is **NOT** repeated. Other questions here are about *creating* configurable products, not reading.

EDIT:
The problem is to solve that only through Magento built-in API. A third party extension is not an option because that Magento instance is only accessible through API.

Answer (score 2):

I have create new  extension which is `give the relational diagram  of simple products and parent Configurable product.`

**Step1>:**  Create `Api.php` at `app\code\local\Amit\SimpleConfigRelation\Model`

this give simple product ids and it reverent  variance  `value and attribute id` and `option id and label`

**code is**

```
<?php
class Amit_SimpleConfigRelation_Model_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Api_Resource
{        
            public function getRelationship($productId, $storeId = null){

             $result = array();
             $this->_configProductId =$productId;
                $product = $this->_getProduct($productId, $storeId);
             $this->_getProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            // $this->_getProduct->setStoreId($storeId);
             $this->_getProduct->load($productId);

             if($this->_getProduct->getId()){
                $result['dropdata']=$this->alldropdownData();

             }
            return $result; 
         }
            public function getChildsByParentId()
        {
        }        
        public function getVarienPrice()
        {
        }

        public function alldropdownData()
        {
            $attributes = array();
            $options    = array();

            $currentProduct = $this->_getProduct;

            $products = array();


            $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            /* getting all all simple products */
            $allProducts = $this->_getProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
                    ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->_getProduct);

            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                $products[] =  $product;
            }

            /* getting all configurable attribute of that products */
            $AllowAttributes=$this->_getProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getConfigurableAttributes($this->_getProduct);

           $producVarien=array();


            foreach ($products as $product) {

                $productsData[$product->getId()]=$product->getData();

                foreach ($AllowAttributes as $attribute) {

                    $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                    $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                    $attributeValue     = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
                    /* Simple Product data */

                    if (!isset($producVarien[$product->getId()])) {

                        $producVarien[$product->getId()] = array();
                    }
                     if (!isset($producVarien[$product->getId()][$productAttributeId])) {
                       $producVarien[$product->getId()][$productAttributeId] = array();
                    }

                    /* getting option text value */
                    if ($productAttribute->usesSource()) {
                         $MYabel = $productAttribute->getSource()->getOptionText($attributeValue );
                    }else{
                         $MYabel='';
                    }
                    $info = array(
                       'id'        => $productAttribute->getId(),
                       'code'      => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
                       'label'     => $attribute->getLabel(),
                       'optionslabel'   => $MYabel
                  );

                     $producVarien[$product->getId()][$productAttributeId] = array('value'=>$attributeValue,'all'=>$info );
                    /* end of simple product data */
                    if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId])) {
                        $options[$productAttributeId] = array();
                    }

                    if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue])) {
                        $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
                    }


                    $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
                }
            }


            return $producVarien;
        }

}
```

**[Result]**

[image]

**Step2:** Create `api.xml` at  `app\code\local\Amit\SimpleConfigRelation\etc` for getting their relation by api access

```
SOAP

$client = new SoapClient('http://yourhost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('******', '******');
$date = $client->call($session, 'simpleconfigrelation_api.getrelationship',array($configproID));


XML-RPC

$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://yourhost/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('******', '******'));
$date=$client->call('call', array($session, 'simpleconfigrelation_api.getrelationship'));
```

**And code of this file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <simpleconfigrelation_api translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                <title>Myapi</title>
                <acl>simpleconfigrelation/api</acl>
                <model>simpleconfigrelation/api</model>
                <methods>                    
                        <getrelationship translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                            <title>Relation Between</title>
                            <acl>simpleconfigrelation/getrelationship</acl>
                        </getrelationship>                    
                        <getchildsbyparentid translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                            <title>Child Product iDs</title>
                            <acl>simpleconfigrelation/getchildsbyparentid</acl>
                        </getchildsbyparentid>                    
                        <getvarienprice translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                            <title>Get Extra price on Varien</title>
                            <acl>simpleconfigrelation/getvarienprice</acl>
                        </getvarienprice>
                </methods>
            </simpleconfigrelation_api>
        </resources>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <simpleconfigrelation translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                    <title>SimpleConfigRelation</title>
                    <sort_order>2000</sort_order>                    
                    <getrelationship translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                        <title>Relation Between</title>
                    </getrelationship>                    
                    <getchildsbyparentid translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                        <title>Child Product iDs</title>
                    </getchildsbyparentid>                    
                    <getvarienprice translate="title" module="simpleconfigrelation">
                        <title>Get Extra price on Varien</title>
                    </getvarienprice>
                </simpleconfigrelation>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

**Step3:** Create `config.xml` at `app\code\local\Amit\SimpleConfigRelation\etc` and

**code is**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Amit_SimpleConfigRelation>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Amit_SimpleConfigRelation>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <simpleconfigrelation>
        <class>Amit_SimpleConfigRelation_Helper</class>
      </simpleconfigrelation>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <simpleconfigrelation>
        <class>Amit_SimpleConfigRelation_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>simpleconfigrelation_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </simpleconfigrelation>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Step4:create module file at `Amit_SimpleConfigRelation.xml` at `app\etc\modules`
and code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Amit_SimpleConfigRelation>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>            
            <depends>
                <Mage_Api />
            </depends>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Amit_SimpleConfigRelation>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Study  on [How can I create a Custom SOAP/XML-RPC v1 & V2 Api in magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/how-can-i-create-a-custom-soap-xml-rpc-v1-v2-api-in-magento)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and hardwork. Unfortunately this is not pure API based solution as the source Magento system might not be accessible and it's not allowed to install extensions. The problem is to solve that only through Magento built-in API.